# How many Soviet space missions have had at least one tortoise?

Tags: history, soviet-union, animals

Science Alert's [These Are 7 of The Strangest Experiments Humans Have Ever Done in Space](https://www.sciencealert.com/wild-space-experiments-conducted-by-humans) talks about two tortoises that flew aboard Zond-5 spacecraft on 2 September 1968, then later goes on to say:

> We'd like to say that no one ever sent tortoises to space again, but... **two more tortoise missions took place.** [Zond 7 in 1969](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/zond-7/in-depth/) carried tortoises. In 1975, the Soyuz 20 spacecraft ferried a tortoise around for 90 days. And two tortoises flew on the [Salyut-5 space station in 1976](http://www.astronautix.com/d/details2008.html).

I count *three more* from the wording of that paragraph;

1. Zond 7 in 1969
2. Soyuz 20 in 1975 (which went to the Salyut-4 space station)
3. Salyut-5 in 1976

**Question:** Have there been four Soviet missions with tortoise payloads *in toto*; Zond 5 and *three more* rather than two?

Comment: related: [Number of nonhuman primates dead in space exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49335/12102)

Comment: Why is it sad that there were tortoise missions?

Comment: re: title spelling: total?

Comment: @AntonHengst here's the problem; I like to show off by implanting latin phrases like *in situ* or *[in toto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(I)#in_toto)* ***ad nauseam*** and the use of latin phrases like that is often done in italics to indicate the phrase is in another language an not simply mipselled (as I have done in the last sentence). However I don't know how to italicize phrases within titles. I've since modified the title, but to make it more "catchy" rather than to address my titular italicization fail.

Comment: @ikrase i've replaced that with an ellipsis because it's not relevant to the question. 20th century use of animals for science and food was pretty brutal on a massive scale throughout the world certainly. Recovery of the first tortoise mission in 1969 took longer than was expected and the tortoise got pretty hungry and perhaps thirsty because of that (no details are given), but I assume in subsequent missions this didn't happen.

Comment: see also: https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2012/12/who-was-first-in-the-race-to-the-moon-the-tortoise/266665/ https://news.google.com/newspapers?id=QycxAAAAIBAJ&sjid=pAEEAAAAIBAJ&dq=zond%205%20turtle&pg=2624%2C4479128 https://repository.si.edu/bitstream/handle/10088/32682/1970.SHIS24.pdf ... (these are more about the original Zond 5 shot than the subsequent experiments)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks! If there is anything there of particular interest please feel free to add an answer with those links, and quoting a few relevant sentences or factoids. Comments are often skipped by future readers and they should be considered temporary and might be deleted in the future or moved to chat, so if there are some goodies then future readers will benefit if these are captured in an answer post.

Comment: I would, but the cool info in these links doesn't really address your question ("how many Soviet payloads have included tortoises?") I will chime in on the [other Zond 5/tortoise-related question on this site](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14614/why-did-the-zond-5-tortoises-lose-body-mass-so-quickly) ...

Comment: @uhoh respectable! I'm snagging this one for my own use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Bion-1 in 1973
- Bion-2 in 1974
- Bion-3 in 1975

http://biosputnik.imbp.ru/download/pdf/BION.pdf (20 pages, in both English and Russian)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bion_(satellite)

Comment: Wow! The BION.pdf is excellent! I now realize that "turtle" and "tortoise" are nonscientific classifications and are somewhat interchangeable, in Russian; черепахи.  I had a few pet [Box Turtles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_turtle) when I was young, and it is hard for me to imagine them floating around an enclosure and "swimming" with any degree of success. Now I'm really curious about both why tortoises were studied to such an extent and the practicalities of their mobility.

Comment: @uhoh I once read the memoirs so that turtles were mentioned. The reason is simple - turtles do not need to be fed for a long time. They can be easily fixed inside the spacecraft. And these turtles were caught in the steppe on the territory of the cosmodrome. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_tortoise

Comment: Oh of course! Yes that certainly makes sense, they can be surprisingly comfortable static, no treadmills necessary for these creatures.